# Compiling embbeded Grizzly Jersey application can't find Jersey Resources

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jersey, gradle, grizzly

I'm working on an application mounted over the Jersey (v2) framework with an embbeded Grizzly server.

Compiling and running in IntelliJ Idea Community 12 works perfect, however when I compile to a ".jar" with Gradle, every http call to the app returns 404.

I can tell the Resources Classes scan is not working because I have a mockup class which returns a warning on startup time and I am not having that warning running the JAR but I do running the app from Idea.

Here is my project structure (Reduced to pertinent things):

```
api
    .idea
    libs
    src
        main
            java
                wci.api
                    main
                        Main.java
                    resource (Here are all resource classes)
    build.gradle
```

This is how I initialize the server in Main.java:

```
package wci.api.main;

// Some imports...

public class Main {
    public static final String BASE_URI = "http://0.0.0.0:4747/";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Some irrelevant code...

        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig();

        rc.packages("wci.api.resource");                   // This does not work
        rc.register(wci.api.main.CorsSupportFilter.class); // This works

        final HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);

        // Some more irrelevant code...
    }
}
```

This is my build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'java'

    repositories{
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies{
        <<< Dependencies >>>

    }

    jar{
        from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
        manifest { attributes 'Main-Class': 'wci.api.main.Main' }
    }
```

This is how I compile my app:

```
gradle build
```

And this is how I run it:

```
java -jar api.jar
```

What's missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also tried compiling the jar from IntelliJ Idea and I have the same result as compiling it with gradle.

Comment: I have found that the commandline that runs Idea works with the jar built with Gradle. It adds a huge "-classpath". I tried adding it on build.gradle with "configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(',')", I see it added on the Manifest but those are not the same dependencies as far as I can tell.

Comment: More info about this. It works properly with "gradle run" but I don't think it's acceptable for a deploy to have all the code and build tools just to run the app.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems I can spot:

- Resources should go into `src/main/resources`, rather than `src/main/java`. (Otherwise you'll have to reconfigure `sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs`.)
- `configurations.compile.collect { ... }` should be `configurations.runtime.collect { ... }`.

Instead of manually creating a fat Jar, I recommend to use Gradle's `application` plugin.

Comment: Nope :(, did not work. I renamed java to resources and configured the application plugin in Gradle I've got the same result after compiling the app with distZip, unpacking and running "bin/api". Again, all works but Jersey can't find what's defined by rc.packages().